# How to remove one of scrolling label from Frame on mouse click at runtime?

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.Font;

import java.awt.FontMetrics;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestLabelMove {

    List<MovingLabel> labels;
    private int count = 1;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private final int SEPARATION = 100;
    private final int SCREEN_W = 1000;
    int XLOC = SCREEN_W;
    private boolean scrollable = true;

    public TestLabelMove() {

        // statusLabel = new JLabel("Status");
        // statusLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Labels");
        // frame.add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(new LabelPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(1000, 75);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private class LabelPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final int INC = 5;

        public LabelPanel() {
            labels = new LinkedList<MovingLabel>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                MovingLabel label = new MovingLabel(XLOC);
                labels.add(label);
                XLOC -= SEPARATION;
                add(label);
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (MovingLabel label : labels) {
                        if (isScrollable()) {
                            if (isWrap(label.getXLoc())) {
                                label.setXLoc(SCREEN_W);
                                label.setLocation(label.getXLoc(), 0);
                            } else {
                                label.setXLoc(label.getXLoc() - INC);
                                label.setLocation(label.getXLoc(), 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    public boolean isWrap(int x) {
        return x <= -40;
    }

    public boolean isScrollable() {
        return scrollable;
    }

    private class MovingLabel extends JPanel {

        int xLoc;
        String phrase;

        public MovingLabel(int xLoc) {
            this.xLoc = xLoc;
            phrase = "Panel " + count;
            count++;

            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    // statusLabel.setText(phrase);
                    JFrame fr = new JFrame();
                    fr.setTitle(phrase);
                    fr.setSize(500, 200);
                    fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    fr.setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("phrase - " + phrase);
                    JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
                    lbl.setText(phrase);
                    fr.add(lbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    JButton bt = new JButton("Completed");
                    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                    // revalidate();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    scrollable = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    scrollable = true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
            int w = fm.stringWidth(phrase);
            int h = fm.getAscent();
            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString(phrase, getWidth() / 2 - w / 2, getHeight() / 2 + h
                    / 2);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 20);
        }

        public void setXLoc(int xLoc) {
            this.xLoc = xLoc;
        }

        public int getXLoc() {
            return xLoc;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestLabelMove();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code also taken from net to learn. It exactly matches my requirement.After removing label on mouse click, it should disappear from scrolling labels from Frame. Please help me. I already crossed my deadlines.This is the first time I am asking doubts in forum. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: *"Please help me. I already crossed my deadlines."*  So let's get this straight. You want to submit code as homework, that you found on the net and we made work according to your need?  Forgive me for helping 10 other people with better scruples **and** time management before I even consider that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create the 'completed' button, and before you add the action listener, put in the following four lines.

```
JButton bt = new JButton("Completed");

JComponent s = (JComponent)e.getSource();
JComponent parent = (JComponent) MovingLabel.this.getParent();
parent.remove(MovingLabel.this);
parent.repaint();

bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
```

This will get the parent from the clicked label. The label is then removed form the parent, and then you perform a repaint.

Comment: -1, Don't use updateUI(). That method is used when the LAF changes. When you dynamically add/remove components from a visible GUI use `revalidate()` and `repaint()`.

Comment: because it doesn't calling revalidate() and repaint()

Comment: OK I replaced updateUI() with repaint(). That seems to have removed the glitch.

Comment: @Oliver Watkins Thank you so much for your timely help. I have been struggling 2 days to remove a particular label. Again one more doubts.

Comment: 2. I have an SLA associated with this with each Label(msg - say 12:00 PM PST). if that time is over(crossed 12:00 PM PST), I will remove that label as per ur above help. I will export this java class as jar and run. When I run the same jar again, the removed SLA(the one with 12:00 PM PST msg ), should not be listed in the scrolling messages. 
Below is the part of the MsgList code. If you explain with above code, it will be easy to understand for me. Below is the sample msgList from XML file after parsing it. Due to size limit unabale to add it.

Comment: so my answer helped? Please accept it and then ask another question